# Grabbing iPad device information programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios6

Is there a way using the public frameworks or APIs to obtain information about the specific iPad device, i.e. the information listed under About of the General tab of the Settings application? I know I can use the UIDevice class to get the UDID (which is now depreciated fo iOS 5.0) and device name. I was wondering if I can extract even more information.

Thanks!

Comment: Be aware that UDID is not only deprecated, but it's use will cause your app to be rejected.

Comment: @RichardBrown is there a non-deprecated way to get a udid then?

Comment: No, you are not allowed to use it at all anymore.  Apple doesn't want you to use it to uniquely identify a device (and in turn potentially the user).

Comment: Is there a way to grab the serial number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something I've used to determine the device:

```
#import <sys/utsname.h>
```

Then to check a device:

```
struct utsname systemInfo;
uname(&systemInfo);
NSString *modelName = [NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.machine encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

if ([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPhone4,1"]) {
    // act accordingly
}
```

See the "Identifier" column on http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Models to see possible devices.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a lot of information about a device from the [UIDevice](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html) class:

- name
- List item
- systemName
- systemVersion
- model
- localizedModel
- userInterfaceIdiom
- identifierForVendor
- orientation
- batteryLevel
- batteryState

I recommend you read the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html) to see all the information you can retrieve.

You should also check out this extension by erica: https://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of useful categories using public, semi-private and private APIs (IOKit primarily) that you can (or cannot, context needed) use. Refer to [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the sysctl system library stuff
I remember not being able to extract all the information as is documented in the [sysctl manpage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/sysctl.3.html) but I remember being able to extract quite a bit of information

Let me know if anything needs to be cleared up